# Get div IDs inside a div via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get the IDs of all the child(1,2,3 etc.) inside the parent1 and put them into an array with jquery.

Just as info, I have a lots of "parents" (parent1, parent2 etc.)

```
<div id="parent1">

  <div id="child1" class="child">
     <div id="baby1" class="baby">TEXT</div>
  </div>

  <div id="child2" class="child">
     <div id="baby2" class="baby">TEXT</div>
  </div>

  <div id="child3" class="child">
     <div id="baby3" class="baby">TEXT</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This is my code:

```
   var save_array = [];
   $('#parent1').find("div",'.child').each(function(){ save_array.push(this.id); });
```

But when I do this, I get the the "baby" too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var arr = $('#parent1').find("div.child").map(function () {
    return this.id;
}).get();
console.log(arr); //["child1", "child2", "child3"]
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/c6TCQ/)

Comment: It works! Thanks - How do I exclude a child if the child example is named "childXX" "Without a number"

Comment: @Chak, `$('#parent1').find("div.child:not(#childXX)")` and `Without a number` I didn't got you

Comment: child1, child2, and if it is named childXX - it should pass that :) - Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
var save_array = [];
$('#parent1').children().each(function(){ 
  save_array.push(this.id); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` will go through all descendants. Use `.children()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var save_array = [];

$("[id*='parent']").find("div.child").each(function(){ 

   save_array.push(this.id);

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct syntax is like this:

```
$('#parent1').find("div.child").each(function(){ 
    save_array.push(this.id);
});
```